# How to use the UISearchController

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

I want to know how to use the `UISearchController`? It seems that the `UISearchDisplayController` was deprecated so I wonder how could I use the `UISearchController`. I have read the Apple Documentation. I get the logic but could not find any simple program for the usage of UISearchController. Hope to get some answer from you.

Comment: Here's an example on apple site itself. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Also seems like you have same question from 2 different accounts. http://stackoverflow.com/q/43859648/3840908 Kindly avoid this in future.